# "Quale/i" o "che" in proposizioni relative

Tags: grammar, pronouns, sentences

I read that we can always use :il/la/li/le quale/quali" instead of "che" or "cui".

If initially the sentence is

> Le ragazze che abbiamo salutato sono francesi,

can we say

> Le ragazze le quali abbiamo salutato sono francesi?

Or what would be the correct corresponding sentence with "le quali"?

Maybe

> Le ragazze con le quali abbiamo salutato sono francesi?

Comment: “we can always use il/la/li/le quale/quali instead of che or cui”: Where did you read that? Like this, it's not true.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: There are differences for transitive and intransitive verbs. "Con le quali" can be used, for example, in "...con le quali abbiamo scherzato..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DaG mentioned in the comments, you can't *always* replace "che" and "chi" with "il quale" & co.

Your example below:

> Le ragazze **le quali abbiamo salutato** sono francesi?

is **incorrect** because this subordinate is a *relativa restrittiva*. It's not simply describing the *ragazze*: it's specifying that the main clause only refers to the *ragazze* you greeted. And as explained by the [Crusca](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/che-o-il-quale_(La-grammatica-italiana)/):

> Le due forme non si possono considerare intercambiabili [...]
> Quando [...] la proposizione relativa determina il nome a cui si
> riferisce distinguendolo in modo univoco da un insieme più ampio di
> persone, animali o cose (relativa *restrittiva*), si può usare solo
> *che*.

There's no corresponding sentence with *le quali* that I can think of, because *salutare + con + qualcuno* is incorrect in Italian. The closest that comes to mind is "Le ragazze **con le quali ci siamo scambiati i saluti** sono francesi" – grammatically correct, but it sounds *very* convoluted.

I also add that "il quale" etc. are from a very formal (esp. written) register.